# What is a good ebook for learning the English language?

Tags: language

I need an ereader application or ebook that can help me learn the English language.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site does not deal with what is written in an ebook but just how it is constructed or read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is question that a simple search with Google can solve, as I did very easy: https://www.myenglishteacher.eu/blog/best-e-books-to-learn-english/

I suppose there are plenty of applications an Android store, sort of speaking.